# Как соединить два SELECT в одном запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

При таком запросе выводит только одно значение из двух таблиц, больше пишет нельзя

```
SELECT (SELECT balance FROM users WHERE id = '{user_request['id']}') AS balance,
        (SELECT id FROM perevody WHERE id = '{user_request['id']}') AS id FROM DUAL;
```

Можно ли как-то соединить результат двух select из разны таблиц в один?

Comment: Без join если можно, просто соединив два селекта.

Comment: а-ля хочу ехать на машине, но на трех колесах, если можно? в чем проблема джойнами?

Comment: Между запросами поставте [`UNION`](https://html5css.ru/sql/sql_union.php)

Comment: В том, что мне нужно получить формат `[{значение1:***, значение2:***}, {значение3:***, значение4:***}]`
join просто все в один объединит

Comment: приведите пример сходных данных и желаемого результата для этих данных. При неоходимости опишите связи этих данных между собой.

Comment: @Random.random Если вам нужен JSON, то это [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)

Comment: `SELECT balance, money, my_money FROM users WHERE id = '{user_request['id']}'
        UNION
SELECT perevod_status FROM perevody WHERE id = '{user_request['id']}';`
Ошибка The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: @Random.random  Ну UNION подразумевает, что количество колонок у всех запросов будет одинаковое

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что каждый из запросов возвращает несколько записей? Правильно ли я понимаю, что {user_request['id']} - это одно значение, а не список?

Comment: *больше пишет нельзя* Сообщение об ошибке нужно цитировать полностью, без изменений и усечений. ОТ "рассказа по мотивам" нет никакого толка.

Comment: @Akina да так, 3 значения из первой, два значения будет из второй, `user_request['id']` просто айдишник по которому поиск идет

Comment: *3 значения из первой, два значения будет из второй* И как в этом случае должен выглядеть результат? Три записи, для второго запроса в последнем поле NULL? Пять записей? шесть записей? ещё лучше - покажите пример вывода запросов по отдельности и требуемого обобщённого результата. да, и укажите ТОЧНУЮ версию MySQL.

Comment: @Random.random Вы ещё и на ходу условия задачи меняете - количество выбираемых полей и т.д. Обновите текст вопроса, чтобы он соответствовал задаче. Перечислите варианты, которые вы пробовали, что с ними не так, какая ошибка вышла. Включите в вопрос всю необходимую информацию, комментарии не для этого предназначены.

Comment: Можно мне просто рассказать как два селекта в одном выводе сделать? И да колонок разное количество будет из первой таблицы и из второй. Или если нельзя, так и напишите, тогда буду джоинами выводить.

Comment: чую по итогу подазапросы (табличное выражение), row_number и фуллджойн по нему

Comment: По итогу иннер джоин.

Comment: вы вот пустословием занимаетесь больше. вас уже дважды попросили привести пример данных и результата. я вот чую, что иннер джойн вам не подойдет.

Comment: Он подошел, но конечно не так хотелось, но что поделать если никто ничего не понял из отписавшихся? Хотя я предельно подробно разъяснил.

Comment: Хотя я простейшую тему спросил, просто не знаю как это синтаксически написать.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно по запросу, что вы пытаетесь вообще сделать и из какой таблицы... Если у вас есть таблицы users и perevody и в perevody у нас есть общий с users 'id' допустим, в колонке perevocy.user_id то я бы сделал так

```
SELECT u.balance AS balance, p.id FROM users u INNER JOIN on u.id = p.user.id WHERE u.id = '{user_request['id']}'
```

Comment: Мне нужен вывод такого плана
`SELECT balance, money, my_money FROM users WHERE id = '{user_request['id']}' UNION SELECT perevod_status FROM perevody WHERE id = '{user_request['id']}';`
Ну тут ошибка типа у колонок разные названия